# REDIS_URL environment variable missing with heroku-redis:in-dyno

Tags: heroku, redis, heroku-ci, heroku-redis

I'm currently using Heroku CI, with the standard **"heroku-redis"** and it works just fine, but I'm now trying to switch to using **"heroku-redis:in-dyno"**.

```
{
    "environments": {
        "test": {
            "addons":[
                "heroku-redis:in-dyno",
                "heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, my builds are now failing.

It appears from the errors in the build that when trying to initialize my application and parse the REDIS_URL environment variable, it's blank, rather than the expected URL.

This URL is set as expected with normal **"heroku-redis"**, just not the **"heroku-redis:in-dyno"** version for some reason.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases indicates it should be set, stating "When a test run begins, you can use the database as normal via DATABASE_URL or REDIS_URL as appropriate. These urls will point to your locally installed database." I'd contact upport.

Comment: Yeah, I read and re-read those docs, just in case I missed something, but as you say, it seems fairly clear that it should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku development team found that this was a bug in the heroku-buildpack-ci-redis, which has since been patched. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ci-redis/commit/71fef260aae271bd77480ae15a6aaaa304c906ea

Hats off to the Heroku team, they were great to work with on spotting and fixing this.